# Replication alternative

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, replication

We are using SQL express that does not support DB replication to other servers.

1- is there any way/free tool that enable us to perform any type of replication?

2- do you have any idea to share the database to other servers rather than replication?

Comment: How many entities do you need to replicate? How frequently do you need them replicated?

Comment: Can you provide more information about what you're trying to achieve with replication and why?

Answer (score 2):

I saw in some installations home-written SQL scripts that mimic SQL transaction log shipping. If you google, you will get plethora of resources. I.e. how to achieve t-log shipping with T-SQL scripts. For example: [LINK](https://learnsqlserverhadr.com/your-poor-mans-sql-server-log-shipping/)

It all boils down to backing up your SOURCE server to shared folder where your TARGET servers have access and the TARGET servers restore these backups from the share.

Please bear in mind you cannot schedule this behaviour with SQL server agent in SQL express (as SQL express does not have SQL agent), you'll need to use OS scheduler for backup and restore.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Server Express supports [Merge Replciation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/replication/merge/merge-replication?view=sql-server-ver15) where changes made at subscribers are synchronized to the publisher and then out to other subscribers in a hub-and-spoke topology.  The "hub" instance is the only "publisher" and would need to be SQL Server Standard Edition or higher.

The other option is to turn on [Change Tracking](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/track-changes/about-change-tracking-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15) and write ETL jobs to extract the changed rows and apply them to another database.